# Disabling Keyboard Events when using a textArea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

My website is meant to be navigated through pressing buttons on the keyboard: <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, etc... My issue is that I have textAreas, and when I press these buttons, if the textArea is selected, the typing and the buttons work at the same time.

I thought the best way to approach this issue would be to use some sort of boolean. I tried to use `if(!x.hasFocus()){ allow buttons to be used}`, but this boolean only applies to the entire document and not specific textAreas.

So how do I disable the event listeners for the keyboard presses only when a textArea is currently being accessed by the user?

I want the user to be able to use <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> when using the textArea, but once the textArea is not being used these buttons should do certain functions, which I am using addEventListener("keyup", function(){...});

Comment: You might want to look into [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Use is in such a way so that the event stops bubbling up on it reaches the textArea element.

Comment: I realized I can use if statements while checking document.activeElement.tagNames === "TEXTAREA"

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
      var typing;
      if(document.activeElement.tagName === "TEXTAREA"){
        typing = true;
       } else{typing = false;}

      if(document.getElementById("body").style.display === "block" && 
document.getElementById("middle").style.display === "none"){
        if(counter < divs.length && event.keyCode === 187 && !typing){
          //do things
        }
      }
```